# Scrollview only horizontally extendable

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I would like to have an extendable horizontal scroll view, I am instantiating images into it, but the images get placed 1st and 2nd horizontally but others go vertically. How should I edit the scroll view, to be able to instantiate only horizontally? Thank you!

The code I am using:

```
public GameObject ItemTemplet;
public Transform Tr;

public void AddIcons()
{
    GameObject createImage = Instantiate(ItemTemplet) as GameObject;
    createImage.transform.SetParent(Tr.transform, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the UI scrollview. **I believe a Horizontal Layout Group component, possibly along with a Content Size Fitter component, might do the trick.** The content fitter will make the size adapt, the Layout group will place them next to each other horizontally. Remember to only set the content fitter for horizontal if you only want it to adapt it's size in that direction. Both should be on the Content part of the scrollview.

This way, if you make an object a child of the Content object in the Scrollview, it will be positioned correctly by the Layout group.

---

Horizontal Layout Group

> The Horizontal Layout Group component places its child layout elements next to each other, side by side.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html

---

Content Size Fitter

> The Content Size Fitter functions as a layout controller that controls the size of its own layout element.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html